# Why are there unwanted duplicated and extra columns in Asp:GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I am trying to show some Details on my Web-Page using the ASP:GridView Control. Accordingly, I have added the columns that I need to show. But, every column is shown twice (Pic) in the GridView .
[image]

By back end Code is as follows:

```
objVendor = client.GetAllVenorsForPCMS();

        if (objVendor.Count > 0)
        {

            gvVendorsDetails.DataSource = objVendor;
            gvVendorsDetails.DataBind();

        }

        else
        {
            gvVendorsDetails.DataSource = null;
            gvVendorsDetails.DataBind();
        }
```

and aspx Code as follows :

```
                <div align="center" style="border: 1px solid;">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvVendorsDetails" runat="server" CssClass="mGrid">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Vendor ID" DataField="VendorID" Visible="false" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Vendor Name" DataField="VendorName" Visible="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Vendor Description" DataField="VendorDescription" Visible="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Address" DataField="Address" Visible="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="City" DataField="City" Visible="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="State" DataField="State" Visible="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Country" DataField="Country" Visible="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Contact Person" DataField="ContactPerson" Visible="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Contact No" DataField="ContactNo" Visible="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ZIP Code" DataField="ZIPCode" Visible="true" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
```

I have added the columns only once, but how come in the result columns are shown Twice !! ?

Comment: yes I do get these columns from my DataBase, but in gridview, dosen't it first try to map the columns coming from Database to the columns set in the Gridview ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A common reason for this is because you also have the [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) property set to true (which is the default). 
By setting the property to false will limit the columns generated to just those you have specified explicitly.

i.e. fix this like so:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvVendorsDetails" runat="server" 
              CssClass="mGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
     <Columns> ...
```